# Why IPv6 addresses are not represented as dotted-decimal like IPv4

Tags: ipv6, ip-address

Maybe this is not a right place for this question, but I didn't find anything better for it.

The text representation of IPv6 addresses defined in [RFC 2373](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2373) states that the addresses should be represented as 8 hexadecimal 16-bit values of the corresponding pieces, such as **2001:0db8:5f62:ab41:0000:0000:0000:0801** or (in abbreviated form) **2001:db8:5f62:ab41::801**

So, what was the reason (RFC 2373 does not state any) not to use "good old" dotted-decimal notation with 16-bit parts (so, the equivalent notation for it would be **8193.3512.24418.43841.0.0.0.2049**)?

This still can be easily distinguished from an IPv4 address (just because of using different number of words and dots) and does not require special syntax (such as brackets) when specifying the port (for example, **[2001:db8:5f62:ab41::801]:8080** looks a bit awkward since it uses the colon for different purposes (separating words in the IP address and the address itself from the port number, so we need brackets), and also mixes decimal (for port) and hex notation).

Comment: There's no good old 16-bit parts. The good old IPv4 notation uses 8-bit parts in base 10. The Q: why did IPv6 feel the need to make such a significant change from IPv4 addresses, and the need for such a huge address space is a legit one. It's a major issue with IPv6 IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32 digit base 16 number is easier for most people to understand than an 8 digit base 65,536 number. Hex is relatively compact, a power of 2, and already used in other contexts like UUIDs, hash functions, and memory addresses.

Bitmasking CIDR notation is easy when staying on 4 bit boundaries = one hex digit.

- `2001:db8:1234::/48`
- `2001:db8:1234:5600::/56`
- `2001:db8:1234:5678::/64`

Also, colon-delimited hex makes it possible to use IPv4 mapped addresses unambiguously. Where the v4 bits are unmodified dotted decimal. For example: `::FFFF:129.144.52.38`.  More about these in RFC 4038.

Sure, bracket wrapping looks a little ugly. Solve that with name resolution; anything you enter into a browser should be in DNS.

See also: [Why is IPv6 expressed in hexadecimal format?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3755/22286)